# How to optimize workflow when frequent model changes are required?

Tags: optimization, architecture, workflow

I have a service, where models change often.

Currently, changing models require changes on different levels, including changing code, SQL queries, protobuf models, documentation, tests...

What are the common approaches to reducing the time required to make a change to the model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My thoughts on this:

- Reduce the dependencies between your components for making changes less cumbersome (design approach: [loose coupling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loose_coupling)).
- Create a model of your dependencies to be clear which impacts a change has in which part of the overall system (e.g. [dependency structure matrix](https://www.ndepend.com/docs/dependency-structure-matrix-dsm)). This should include test and documentation.
- Aim for having many things changable by configuration.
- Automate things (e.g. [automated generation of documentation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_documentation_generators))

Hope this gives you an idea of what to look at.